# Vuejs and Slick Carousel - problem with v-for can't add element in carousel

Tags: vue.js, slick.js

I'm using [vue-slick](https://github.com/staskjs/vue-slick) component but I have some problem with the `v-for` loop.

This is my code:

```
<slick
                        ref="slick"
                        :options="slickOptions"
                        class="float-left full-width slider-ingredients">
                            <div
                                v-for="ingredient in available_prots_source"
                                :key="ingredient.id"
                                @click="onSelectIngredient(ingredient.id, 'prots')"
                                class="slider-ingredient-item">
                                <div class="float-left ingredient-image">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <img :src="ingredient.image" width="200" height="200" class="float-left cover-fit">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="float-left full-width text-center ingredient-name">
                                    {{ingredient.name}}
                                </h4>
                                <span class="float-left full-width text-center ingredient-details">
                                    dettagli
                                </span>
                            </div>
                    </slick>
```

The problem is that my div is added outside the slick container. If I add a `<div>` just after the `<slick>` opening tag it render correctly but sees just one element even if my `v-for` add 4 or 5 elements.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I use slick with `v-for` loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the official README (see method reInit in the [README.md](https://github.com/staskjs/vue-slick)

```
// Helpful if you have to deal with v-for to update dynamic lists
this.$nextTick(() => {
  this.$refs.slick.reSlick();
});
```